What TV series featured a skit about airplanes behaving like birds?
I watched a comedy TV series that included many weird situations. I remember two:

It had a CGI animation of some airplanes landing on an airfield and behaving like birds, bending their wings, and eating like a bird from the ground.
It had a skit where a woman was playing a dance-mat type game on her TV. The dance mat light up telling her where to step. The dance mat formed a path, leading her out of the house and down the street. She came to an abandoned warehouse where she there was a strange alien-like machine.

I believe the series was from Russia.
Does anyone know the name of this skit?

Could this be Mult lichnosti?
